# Golang AES decrypt video before streaming it though http

Tags: go, video-streaming, aes

Im trying to stream AES encrypted video file; however we need to decrypt it on the fly before streaming it though http

how to write the output of decrypted data to http writer

```
 package main

        import (
            "crypto/aes"
            "crypto/cipher"
            "io"
            "log"
            "net/http"
            "os"
        )

        var key []byte = []byte("yourAESPrivateKey")

        func ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            inFile, err := os.Open("2.ts")
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            defer inFile.Close()

            block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
                return
            }
            var iv [aes.BlockSize]byte
            stream := cipher.NewOFB(block, iv[:])
            w.Header().Set("Content-type", "video/mp4")
            writer := &cipher.StreamWriter{S: stream, W: w}

            if _, err := io.Copy(writer, inFile); err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
                return
            }

            //http.ServeContent(w, r, "video.mp4", time.Now(), inFile)
        }

        func main() {
            http.HandleFunc("/", ServeHTTP)
            http.ListenAndServe(":2020", nil)
        }
```

Comment: someone downvoted me, why?

Comment: Because even if you did the decryption, it would not work. You can just read a ts, decrypt it and tell the browser its mp4. You need to convert into a streamable fragmented format, generate manifests, etc.

Comment: Is your problem with decrypting? Is your problem with streaming? What do you expect to happen and what actually happens?

Comment: decryption is ok, my question was : "how to write the output of decrypted data to http.ResponseWriter"

Answer (score -1):

i have enhanced my code

so if i requested an encrypted file, the server will decrypt it and serve it properly, however i have another problem as below

the  problem now is that i get corrupted file if file exceeds certain size.

i have done some tests on text files for debugging purposes and so i can post data results here ([big corrupted file](http://45.76.150.166/big.txt)) check the end of the file

```
package main

        import (
            "crypto/aes"
            "crypto/cipher"
            "log"
            "net/http"
            "os"
            "time"
        )

        type cipherHttpWriter struct {
            http.ResponseWriter
        }

        func (c cipherHttpWriter) Write(b []byte) (int, error) {
            var key []byte = []byte("we!@09bsa$.a-ala.HJOqweK45aghf&A")
            block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
            if err != nil {
                return 0, err
            }
            var iv [aes.BlockSize]byte
            stream := cipher.NewOFB(block, iv[:])
            streamWriter := &cipher.StreamWriter{S: stream, W: c.ResponseWriter}
            defer streamWriter.Close()
            return streamWriter.Write(b)
        }

        func ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            inFile, err := os.Open(string(r.URL.Path[1:]))
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            defer inFile.Close()
            writer := cipherHttpWriter{}
            writer.ResponseWriter = w

            http.ServeContent(writer, r, "", time.Now(), inFile)
        }

        func main() {
            http.HandleFunc("/", ServeHTTP)
            http.ListenAndServe(":2020", nil)
        }
```

Comment: this won't work. decrypted content size does not match AES encrypted content size (due to IV's and nonces, which vary depending on aes encryption mode). The encrypted file is passed directly to http.ServeContent, thus http content range requests, (e.g. resume download), and the reported file size to the browser are all encrypted file sizes, not the decrypted file size.

I've written a proprietary io.ReaderWriter with auto reader.seek(fileOffset int64) conversion between original and the encrypted file on disk. This would be a start towards an possible solution.